# Post multiple value using ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

How I can post all the information in database to it's designated textboxes. I need to post the value on textboxes for example, Pr # data into pr_num textboxes and so on. The problem is my ajax function is only for one textboxes. How I can post it in every textboxes? Any Help will appreciate.

**Table Structure**

```
Pr #  | Supplier  | Receipt #  | Receiver  |
--------------------------------------------
321-B | Villman   | 312312331  | John      |
556-B | Dockers   | 903232317  | William   |
```

**Ajax.php**

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['pr_code'])) {
$pr_code= $_POST['pr_code'];

$sql = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM pr_table WHERE pr='$pr_code'");

while($row = $sql->fetch_assoc())
  {
  $pr= $row['pr'];
  $supplier = $row['supplier'];
  $receipt_num= $row['receipt_num'];
  $receiver= $row['receiver'];
  }
echo $pr;
echo $supplier;
echo $receipt_num;
echo $receiver;
}
?>
```

index.php

```
<select id="pr">
<?php ... ?>
</select>

<input id="pr_num">
<input id="supplier">
<input id="receipt">
<input id="receiver">

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function()
{
$('input[id="pr"]').change(function()
{
var prjt_code = $("#pr").val();
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "ajax.php",
data :"pr_code="+pr_code,
dataType:'html',
type:'POST',
   success:function(data){
    $('#pr_num').val(data);
   }
  });
return false;
});
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

get the other textbox values also and post like below

```
var pr_num= $("#pr_num").val();
var supplier= $("#supplier").val();
var receipt= $("#receipt").val();
var receiver= $("#receiver").val();
```

and in ajax

```
data :{"pr_code":pr_code,"supplier":supplier,"receipt":receipt_num,"receiver":receiver}
```

---

**UPdate**

in php do like this

```
echo json_encode(array("pr" => $pr, "supplier" => $supplier,"receipt_num"=>$receipt_num,"receiver"=>$receiver));
```

in ajax

get values like

```
var pr=data.pr;
var supplier=data.supplier;
var receipt_num=receipt_num;
var receiver=receiver;
```

---

**UPDATE2**

```
you have to add another option value,so that the onchange event will fired. If you have only one value then the change event will not be called.So add another option.
```

and why are you printing `echo $option;` outside option tag??

```
<select id="tag">
<option value="">wala</option><?php echo $option; ?>//what are you trying to do here
</select>
```

Comment: The value of selectbox is the one who use to get information in database. What I need is to post the other information to it's designated textboxes based on value of selectbox.

Comment: Where should I place this in ajax? Pardon me not that good in jquery/ajax.

Comment: I'll make just a try, sorry now I understand :)

Comment: my problem is how I can post the value in right fields. pr value should post only in pr_num field.

Comment: simple `$("#pr_num").val()=pr;` the value in pr will be added to pr_num textbox. FIRST you check whether you are getting the values or not,just try `alert(pr);`

Comment: I already try it. success:function(data){
var pr=data.pr;
var supplier=data.supplier;
alert(pr);
 $('#approved').val()=pr;
 $('#designation_a').val()=supplier;
   } But no alert.

Comment: and what you have changed in php?

Comment: while($row = $sql->fetch_assoc())
  {
  $pr= $row['pr'];
  $supplier = $row['requested'];
  }
  echo json_encode(array("pr" => $pr, "supplier" => $supplier));
}

Comment: try adding this before echo json encode `header('Content-Type: application/json');` and in your php there shouldNOT be any echos except echo json encode

Comment: in both ajax.php and index.php?

Comment: please update your question with the changes you've done or create a pastbin link for your code and share it here.i want to see exactly what you've modified

Comment: I have a query that holds records to make a selectbox that's the value is from database. Pardon I forgot to add this <?php
 $combo = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM purchase_request GROUP BY pr ORDER BY id");
 $option = '';
 while($row = $combo->fetch_assoc())
  {
  $option .= '<option value = "'.$row['pr'].'">'.$row['pr'].'</option>';
  }
?>

Comment: if you have multiple options then its fine,i suggest you to check(by alerting and echoing) the values everywhere in the flow of your code from ajax request to reposnse.

Answer (score 0):

Encode the mysql query results into a json array, then in your javascript function, parse the data with JSON.parse, then loop over it and create the elements using the pr id and set the values or dynamically create the form elements from here

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['pr_code']))
{
        $pr_code= $_POST['pr_code'];
        $sql = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM pr_table WHERE pr='$pr_code'");

        while($row = $sql->fetch_assoc())
        {
                $results[$i++] = $row;
        }      

        json_encode($results);

}
?>


<input id="pr_num">
<input id="supplier">
<input id="receipt">
<input id="receiver">

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function()
{
        $('input[id="pr"]').change(function()
        {
                var prjt_code = $("#pr").val();

                $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "ajax.php",
                        data :"pr_code="+pr_code,
                        dataType:'html',
                        type:'POST',

                        success:function(data)
                        {
                                var json = JSON.parse(data);

                                $.each(json, function(item)                    
                                {                      

                                        //assuming the field names are "pr", "supplier", "receipt", "receiver"

                                        var pr_code = json[item].pr;
                                        var supplier = json[item].supplier;
                                        var receipt = jsonitem].receipt;
                                        var receiver = json[item].receivor;


                                        //TODO: display results here


                                });


                                $('#pr_num').val(data);
                        }
                });
                return false;
        });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Pardon me, but I don't know how to use JSON. Can give me a sample?

Comment: Added an example, Something similar to this should do the trick!

Comment: how to send the output to it's own textboxes? I should create another like this $('#supplier').val(data); ?

Comment: Yeah i think so, I would just create them and set the values